# Nodejs npm scripts fail with "SyntaxError: Unexpected token {"

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu, npm-scripts

I've just imported my Reactjs project to a new machine on Ubuntu and installed most dependencies with `npm install` successfully bar the following:

```
npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /react-scripts/fsevents:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.0.17
npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /chokidar/fsevents:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.1.2
```

Trying to run the project with `npm start` fails with:

```
> booking-frontend@0.1.0 start /root/17-visit-booker-frontend
> react-scripts start


/root/17-visit-booker-frontend/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/start.js:33
const {
      ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:374:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:442:10)
    at startup (node.js:136:18)
    at node.js:966:3

npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-81-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v4.2.6
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! booking-frontend@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the booking-frontend@0.1.0 start script 'react-scripts start'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the booking-frontend package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     react-scripts start
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs booking-frontend
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls booking-frontend
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /root/17-visit-booker-frontend/npm-debug.log
```

Attempting to run any `npm` script including `npm run build` all fails with the exact same error referencing the same lines in each file in the SyntaxError:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:374:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:442:10)
    at startup (node.js:136:18)
    at node.js:966:3
```

Running the same scripts on my original machine, a Mac, succeed.

I've tried re-installing `node`/`npm` which do not fix the issue. Is the supposedly optional dependency causing this to fail?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: And what is at /root/17-visit-booker-frontend/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/start.js:33, line 33?

Comment: Lines 33 - 38: `const {
  choosePort,
  createCompiler,
  prepareProxy,
  prepareUrls,
} = require('react-dev-utils/WebpackDevServerUtils');` where the only thing occupying line 33 is `const {` and each comma-separated item is on a new line.

Comment: Although this referenced line will change depending on what script I run but will always fail when it hits a curly brace. It then fails with a SyntaxError and quotes the above stack trace which is identical no matter what script it fails on. Running `npm run build` causes it to complain with : `/root/17-visit-booker-frontend/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/build.js:60
    ({ stats, previousFileSizes, warnings }) => {` and points at the first occurrence of a curly brace.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're using node.js v4 which does not by default support destructuring syntax (the `const {field1, field2, ....} = object`) that it is failing on.

You have two options:

1. Install a newer version of Node.js
2. Run node with the harmony flags that will enable this feature in version 4.x.

Comment: The specific flag that would enable this is `--harmony-destructuring`, so running `node --harmony-destructuring` should allow this to be used.

Comment: Thanks for this! I'm surprised how little results about this turned up when I was googling this problem.

Comment: Node 8 wasn't working for me either. I swapped to 12 and it no longer gave me an error