# create-react-library cannot run npm start

Tags: node.js, npm

I cloned create-react-library from https://github.com/UdiliaInc/create-react-library but cannot get it to start.

I have made no edits. I ran npm install and then npm start. When I run npm start I get the same error described in the below post.

[Nodejs npm scripts fail with "SyntaxError: Unexpected token {"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45108189/nodejs-npm-scripts-fail-with-syntaxerror-unexpected-token)

I checked my node version and it is 5.3.0. Any other reasons why this could be happening?

The error is

```
  `[clynch@localhost create-react-library]$ npm start

create-react-library@1.0.0 start /home/clynch/git/create-react-library
node scripts/start.js

/home/clynch/git/create-react-library/scripts/start.js:23
    const { choosePort,
          ^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
        at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
        at Module._compile (module.js:374:25)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:405:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
        at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:430:10)
        at startup (node.js:141:18)
        at node.js:980:3
    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    npm ERR! errno 1
    npm ERR! create-react-library@1.0.0 start: `node scripts/start.js`
    npm ERR! Exit status 1
    npm ERR! 
    npm ERR! Failed at the create-react-library@1.0.0 start script.
    npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     /home/clynch/.npm/_logs/2017-11-16T21_05_24_465Z-debug.log
    `
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should update your node version to 6.12 or 7+

For reference, check http://node.green/